# Does this helium mixture make it less poisonous?

Tags: breathing

I've heard about accidental helium overdoses from people trying to inhale it to make a funny voice. But when looking [at some products](https://www.target.com/p/8-9-cu-ft-helium-balloon-kit/-/A-13567277), I see they're sold at a mix of 80% helium, 20% air.

> "Net contents: mixture of helium and air containing not less than 80% helium."

Does this make them less deadly/dangerous, or could you still overdose by inhaling this diluted mixture?

Comment: That would be a good question for you to answer in your post because prior research is required here.

Comment: Why did you delete the comment I responded to above? Your question was: "Additionally, is this a new safeguard, or has balloon helium always been an 80/20 mix?"

Comment: Helium is not poisonous. It's completely inert and harmless as long as you're breathing a normal amount of oxygen along with it, and 20% O2 happens to be a normal amount. That's the easy answer to your question. Honestly, the better question is whether the helium sold to consumers has always contained 20% O2. I suspect the answer is no because I know of suicides where helium purchased from party stores has been used as an asphyxiant. If it contained 20% O2, that wouldn't have been an effective suicide method.

Comment: @CareyGregory Sorry I deleted my comment. It sounded like I had asked a bad question, so I removed it. However, I did a quick search and found that the 80/20 mix was started in 2015 in the US to avoid accidental (or purposeful) poisoning. I'd post the link, but it was from a pretty grim source.

Comment: In medicine, we use [Heliox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heliox) (80/20, 79/21, 70/30, even 60/40) for partial upper airway obstructions, as it is thinner than air and easier to breathe/pass through the obstruction.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.